# Create pdf which content html and gujarati text in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, dompdf

I have try to create pdf in Laravel.
Use`barryvdh/laravel-dompdf` vendor package class.
My pdf content English and Gujarati text.
but gujarati content print as ?????? in pdf.

I have create pdf succesfully use this type of code
pdfview is my pdf php, html content file view

```
    view()->share('data',$data);
    $pdf = PDF::loadView('pdfview');
    return $pdf->stream('pdfview.pdf');
    // return $pdf->download('pdfview.pdf');
```

I have expected to pdf content as English and Gujarati text content.
Actual result in pdf Gujarati content print like ????

Comment: DId you found solution?

Answer (score 0):

use `wkhtmltopdf`, make sure to install all unicode library related to Gujarati language. I tried it for sinhala in ubuntu and centos.

Answer (score 0):

"????" is because the font in not there by default in barryvdh/laravel-dompdf package.
1.You need to download the fonts that supports gujrati.
2.After downloading, just put the the .ttf file to your font assets folder.
3.Then use the css @font-face to explicitly declare your font supporting the gujrati characters.
Just for example (using simhei.ttf). FYI, this is in my template.blade.php file

```
<style type="text/css">
@font-face {
   font-family: SimHei;
   src: url('{{base_path().'/public/report_assets/'}}fonts/simhei.ttf') format('truetype');
}

* {
  font-family: SimHei;
}
</style>

<body>
//gujrati characters
.......
```

Thats it